# How to align table content to the right with stacked responsive table

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

When using desktop, the right "td"'s content is now left aligned, how can I right align the content of this "td"?

When using mobile, the two "td"s will stack on top of each other and center align the contents. This is exactly what I want.

My problem is, when using desktop, I want to right align the right "td". How can I do this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.table-responsive-stack').each(function(i) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    //alert(id);
    $(this).find("th").each(function(i) {
      $('#' + id + ' td:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')').prepend('<span class="table-responsive-stack-thead">' + $(this).text() + ':</span> ');
      $('.table-responsive-stack-thead').hide();

    });
  });

  $('.table-responsive-stack').each(function() {
    var thCount = $(this).find("th").length;
    var rowGrow = 100 / thCount + '%';
    //console.log(rowGrow);
    $(this).find("th, td").css('flex-basis', rowGrow);
  });

  function flexTable() {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
      $(".table-responsive-stack").each(function(i) {
        $(this).find(".table-responsive-stack-thead").show();
        $(this).find('thead').hide();
      });
      // window is less than 768px   
    } else {
      $(".table-responsive-stack").each(function(i) {
        $(this).find(".table-responsive-stack-thead").hide();
        $(this).find('thead').show();
      });
    }
    // flextable
  }

  flexTable();
  window.onresize = function(event) {
    flexTable();
  };

});
```

```css
.table-responsive-stack tr {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.table-responsive-stack td,
.table-responsive-stack th {
  display: block;
  /*      
            flex-grow | flex-shrink | flex-basis   */
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.table-responsive-stack .table-responsive-stack-thead {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .table-responsive-stack tr {
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  .table-responsive-stack tr td {
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-top: 0 !important;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
  }
  /*  IE9 FIX   */
  .table-responsive-stack td {
    float: left\9;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.2/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" integrity="sha512-uzG4YY/dpwIEUrfjYud6T7ieVM06DwkHYiB28wgbtq0w4hSGx3XyDF2Oh/VaxB0hmyxyR3hYHNQc4Chb/dS1Sw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table align-middle mb-0 table-responsive-stack" style="table-layout: fixed;" id="tableOne">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
            <div class="mr-2 text-success"><i class='bx bxs-coin-stack font-18 me-1'></i></div>
            <div class="mr-2">Redeem xxx Coins</div>
            <div class="mr-2 text-tertiary"><i class='lni lni-question-circle font-18 me-1'></i></div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
            <div class="text-tertiary" id="redeed_coins_value">[- $5]</div>
            <label class="pointer ml-4">
                    <input type="checkbox" value=""></label>
            <br>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code snippet isn't showing the problem.